# How to use AD Attributes not represented in the Principal Class

Tags: c#, active-directory

The `Principal` class only have a few AD attributes :

[image]

The problem is I need to read a property that is not in the `Principal` Class...

Here's how I query the AD object :

```
// create your domain context
PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain,ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADDomain"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADUser"].ToString(), ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ADPassword"].ToString());

// define a "query-by-example" principal - here, we search for all users
UserPrincipalEXT qbeUser = new UserPrincipalEXT(ctx);

// create your principal searcher passing in the QBE principal    
PrincipalSearcher srch = new PrincipalSearcher(qbeUser);

// find all matches
foreach (var found in srch.FindAll()) //FOUND represent the AD object
{
    ...
}
```

Is there a way to extend the `Principal` class to get more AD properties ?

Answer (score 4):

If you're on .NET 3.5 and up and using the `System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement` (S.DS.AM) namespace, you can easily extend the existing `UserPrincipal` class to get at more advanced properties, like `Manager` etc.

Read all about it here:

- [Managing Directory Security Principals in the .NET Framework 3.5](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc135979.aspx)
- [MSDN docs on System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.aspx)

Basically, you just define a derived class based on `UserPrincipal`, and then you define your additional properties you want:

```
[DirectoryRdnPrefix("CN")]
[DirectoryObjectClass("Person")]
public class UserPrincipalEx : UserPrincipal
{
    // Inplement the constructor using the base class constructor. 
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context) : base(context)
    { }

    // Implement the constructor with initialization parameters.    
    public UserPrincipalEx(PrincipalContext context,
                         string samAccountName,
                         string password,
                         bool enabled) : base(context, samAccountName, password, enabled)
    {} 

    // Create the "Department" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("department")]
    public string Department
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("department").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("department")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("department", value); }
    }

    // Create the "Manager" property.    
    [DirectoryProperty("manager")]
    public string Manager
    {
        get
        {
            if (ExtensionGet("manager").Length != 1)
                return string.Empty;

            return (string)ExtensionGet("manager")[0];
        }
        set { ExtensionSet("manager", value); }
    }
}
```

Now, you can use the "extended" version of the `UserPrincipalEx` in your code:

```
using (PrincipalContext ctx = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
{
    // Search the directory for the new object. 
    UserPrincipalEx inetPerson = UserPrincipalEx.FindByIdentity(ctx, IdentityType.SamAccountName, "someuser");

    // you can easily access the Manager or Department now
    string department = inetPerson.Department;
    string manager = inetPerson.Manager;
}
```

Comment: @marc_s I'm using .NET 4.7 still not get property like manager

Comment: What is `ExtensionGet` ?

Comment: @Kiquenet: a method on the `Principal` class, from which `UserPrincipal` inherits - see details here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.principal.extensionget?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0#system-directoryservices-accountmanagement-principal-extensionget(system-string)

Answer (score 2):

You can use GetUnderlyingObject() to access additional properties:

```
if (found.GetUnderlyingObjectType() == typeof(DirectoryEntry))
{
    DirectoryEntry de = (DirectoryEntry)principal.GetUnderlyingObject();
    // Use de.Properties to access additional information
}
```

Comment: list for all properties using in AD ?